# Python 2.7 os.EX_SOFTWARE not found

Tags: python, python-2.7

I `import os` and, in my exception handling, I have `sys.exit(os.EX_SOFTWARE)`, but Python 2.7 is reporting

> File "H:/code/testgen/testGen.py", line 87, in SyntaxCheck
>       sys.exit(os.EX_SOFTWARE) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'EX_SOFTWARE' ERROR, UNEXPECTED EXCEPTION 'module' object
>   has no attribute 'EX_SOFTWARE'

What am I doing wrongly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `os.EX_<something>` error codes are only available on Unix systems, such as Linux and Mac, but it looks like you're trying to run this on Windows. The value of `os.EX_SOFTWARE` is 70, so use this instead:

```
sys.exit(70)
```

This works because Windows treats any non-0 exit code as an error.

Comment: Is there an alternative? Something cross-platform?

Comment: This is cross-platform; on Windows it exits with an error, and on Unix it exits with error code 70, which is the same as `os.EX_SOFTWARE`.

Comment: To clarify, if I do  `python -c "import sys; sys.exit(70)" && echo Success` on either my Windows machine or my Mac, `Success` is never printed because the Python operation exited with an error. If I change `sys.exit(70)` to `sys.exit(0)`, which would be a success, both machines then print `Success`.